# Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to make MultiProvider.I don't know where the error is. I'm a new Dart and Flutter. Try to fix it by myself but can't fix it. When I run the project it stuck on the error screen. I'm attaching the picture with the question.

[This pic shows error display on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJqm1.png)

Here are my codes main.dart file

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:vendorapp/providers/auth_providers.dart';
import 'package:vendorapp/screens/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:vendorapp/screens/registerscreen.dart';
import 'package:vendorapp/screens/splashscreen.dart';

void main() async {
  //Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp( MultiProvider(
      providers:[
        Provider (create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
      ],
    child: MyApp(),
  )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      ),
      initialRoute: SplashScreen.id,
      routes: {
        SplashScreen.id: (context) => SplashScreen(),
        RegisterScreen.id: (context) => RegisterScreen(),
        HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here are my image_picker.dart file

````
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:vendorapp/providers/auth_providers.dart';

class ShopPicCard extends StatefulWidget {

  const ShopPicCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShopPicCardState createState() => _ShopPicCardState();
}

class _ShopPicCardState extends State<ShopPicCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _authData = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    File? _image;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          _authData.getImage().then((image){
            setState(() {
              _image = image;
            });
            if(image!=null){
              _authData.isPicAvail = true;
            }
          });
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          child: Card(
            child: _image == null ? Center(child: Text('Add Shop Image',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.greenAccent),)
            ):Image.file(_image!,fit: BoxFit.fill,),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

    ```


Here are the error Logs
````

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
D/FlutterLocationService(27889): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(27889): Binding to location service.
D/LocationPlugin(27889): Service connected: ComponentInfo{com.example.vendorapp/com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService}
D/EGL_emulation(27889): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e705ea0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e703810)
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58245/8VdeXtRD7tk=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/zygote  (27889): Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=21KB
I/zygote  (27889): After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=21KB
I/zygote  (27889): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/EGL_emulation(27889): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e6909e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e7036a0)

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building ShopPicCard(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope], state: _ShopPicCardState#396e1):
Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (AuthProvider).

This is likely a mistake, as Provider will not automatically update dependents
when AuthProvider is updated. Instead, consider changing Provider for more specific
implementation that handles the update mechanism, such as:

- ListenableProvider
- ChangeNotifierProvider
- ValueListenableProvider
- StreamProvider

Alternatively, if you are making your own provider, consider using InheritedProvider.

If you think that this is not an error, you can disable this check by setting
Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType to `null` in your main file:

```
void main() {
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ShopPicCard file:///C:/Users/The%20Cubix/StudioProjects/vendorapp/lib/screens/registerscreen.dart:15:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:provider/src/provider.dart:376:9)
#1      Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType.<anonymous closure> (package:provider/src/provider.dart:403:6)
#2      new Provider.<anonymous closure> (package:provider/src/provider.dart:215:56)
#3      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value.<anonymous closure> (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:700:48)
#4      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:702:10)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99203 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/The%20Cubix/StudioProjects/vendorapp/lib/screens/registerscreen.dart:13:18
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#17888 relayoutBoundary=up2 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=796.6)
...  size: Size(411.4, 796.6)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
  child 1: RenderErrorBox#69883
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: Size(411.4, 100000.0)
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: You should mark Valentin's answer as the accepted answer. I arrived here today via search, and it looked like his answer wasn't "right" but it was, solved my problem.  Marking the answer that solved your problem as Accepted helps people (like me).

Answer (score 6):

In your `main` method, and in your `runApp` call. Try to replace

```dart
Provider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
```

with the proper provider.

If `AuthProvider` is a `Stream`, use `StreamProvider`

```dart
StreamProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
```

If `AuthProvider` is a `ChangeNotifier`, use `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
```

If `AuthProvider` is another type of listenable object (I can't tell from the code you provided), try to replace `Provider` with the correct type (`ListenableProvider` or `ValueListenableProvider`).

Comment: Thanks for your replay but if see the main dart file I'm useing runApp( MultiProvider(
      providers:[
        Provider (create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
      ],
    child: MyApp(),
  )

Comment: yes, so try to modify this line with what I have explained in my answer. Ex for `ChangeNotifierProvider` :  `runApp( MultiProvider( providers:[ ChangeNotifierProvider (create: (_) => AuthProvider()), ], child: MyApp(), )`

Comment: Thanks a lot, man it's properly working now. You save my day.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to validate the answer to help the future readers ;)

Comment: Is it still happening with the `AuthProvider` or is it another provider? If yes, did you make sure you used the correct provider? ( `StreamProvider` `ChangeNotifierProvider` )

Comment: Brother I'm using this `ChangeNotifierProvider : runApp( MultiProvider(
      providers:[
        Provider (create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
      ],
    child: MyApp(),
  )` what you said to do.

Comment: You should do this instead: `runApp( MultiProvider(       providers:[         ChangeNofitierProvider (create: (_) => AuthProvider()),       ],     child: MyApp(),   )`  (assuming `AuthProvider` is a `ChangeNotifier` )

Comment: I was doing it but it not fix. and giving the error

Comment: Can you confirm your error is still happening with `AuthProvider`? If yes, and if you used the `ChangeNotifierProvider`, you must have a different error now, can you tell me what it is?

Comment: Thanks for your reply everything is working properly.Now there is no issues

Comment: you are welcome, as I said earlier, don't forget to accept the answer for future readers